# Not able to accommodate the two tables one beside the other, running out of margin

Tags: tables, cross-referencing, align, longtable, labels

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{table}[H]
       \caption{\label{tabss:something}}        
       \begin{subtable}{.5\linewidth}
          \centering
            \caption{\label{tabss1:ss1}}
            \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    \textbf{Parameter} & \textbf{Value}\\
    \hline
    a & {\SI{51}{\ohm}}\\
    \hline
    b & {\SI{952}{\pico\farad}}\\
    \hline
    c & {\SI{952}{\pico\farad}}\\
    \hline
    d & {\SI{6656}{\micro\henry}}\\
    \hline
    e & {\SI{656}{\micro\henry}}\\
    \hline
    f & {\SI{55}{\micro\henry}}\\
    \hline
    g & {\SI{1}{\ohm}}\\
    \hline
    h & {\SI{1}{\ohm}}\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular} 
        \end{subtable}%
        \begin{subtable}{.5\linewidth}
          \centering
            \caption{\label{tabss2:ss2}}
            \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textit{\textbf{topic_23}}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textit{\textbf{$topic_1$ \linebreak in \SI{}{\kilo\hertz}}}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textit{\textbf{$ad$ \linebreak in \SI{}{\kilo\hertz}}}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textit{\textbf{$af$}}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textit{\textbf{$ah$}}} \\
    \hline
    0.1 & 11.3 & 13.75 & 170 & 149\\
    \hline
    0.2 & 10.3 & 15.42 & 180 & 145\\
    \hline
    0.3 & 9.5 & 17.62 & 184 & 135\\
    \hline
    0.4 & 8.8 & 20.55 & 191 & 126\\
    \hline
    0.5 & 8.24 & 24.66 & 198 & 115\\
    \hline
    0.6 & 7.71 & 30.83 & 204 & 103\\
    \hline
    0.7 & 7.26  & 41.09 & 211 & 89\\
    \hline
    0.8 & 6.86 & 61.64 & 217 & 73\\
    \hline
    0.9 & 6.5 & 123.26 & 223 & 52\\
    \hline
    1.0 & 6.17 & -- & 229 & --\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
        \end{subtable} 
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

The right one runs out of margin.

Also this method is not efficient in the way of labeling.

I have this kind of table grouping 3 times further and the labeling are mixed up. Ex: table.1 is referred to above to tables. Next table will be named table.3  which will again contain two sub tables. again next table will be named table.5

Instead the reference should be like table.1, table.2 and then table.3
I dont have an idea why this is happening.

Comment: Should the two tables have a separate caption and be labeled “Table 1” and “Table 2”?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution, using `makecell` (allows line breaks in cells and a common formatting) and changing the widths of the two subtables:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, longtable}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{table-number-alignment=center}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{showframe}%
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.3pt}
\usepackage{makecell}%
\renewcommand\theadfont{\itshape\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
       \caption{\label{tabss:something}}
       \begin{subtable}{.4\linewidth}
          \centering
            \caption{\label{tabss1:ss1}}
            \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    \textbf{Parameter} & \textbf{Value}\\
    \hline
    a & {\SI{51}{\ohm}}\\
    \hline
    b & {\SI{952}{\pico\farad}}\\
    \hline
    c & {\SI{952}{\pico\farad}}\\
    \hline
    d & {\SI{6656}{\micro\henry}}\\
    \hline
    e & {\SI{656}{\micro\henry}}\\
    \hline
    f & {\SI{55}{\micro\henry}}\\
    \hline
    g & {\SI{1}{\ohm}}\\
    \hline
    h & {\SI{1}{\ohm}}\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\hfill
        \end{subtable}%
        \begin{subtable}{.6\linewidth}
          \centering
            \caption{\label{tabss2:ss2}}
            \begin{tabular}{|c|S[table-format=2.2]|S[table-format=3.2]|*{2}{S[table-format=3.0]|}}
    \hline
    \thead{topic\textsubscript{23}} & {\thead{topic\textsubscript{1} \\ in \si{\kilo\hertz}}} &{ \thead{ad \\ in \si{\kilo\hertz}}} & {\thead{af}} & {\thead{ah}} \\
    \hline
    0.1 & 11.3 & 13.75 & 170 & 149\\
    \hline
    0.2 & 10.3 & 15.42 & 180 & 145\\
    \hline
    0.3 & 9.5 & 17.62 & 184 & 135\\
    \hline
    0.4 & 8.8 & 20.55 & 191 & 126\\
    \hline
    0.5 & 8.24 & 24.66 & 198 & 115\\
    \hline
    0.6 & 7.71 & 30.83 & 204 & 103\\
    \hline
    0.7 & 7.26 & 41.09 & 211 & 89\\
    \hline
    0.8 & 6.86 & 61.64 & 217 & 73\\
    \hline
    0.9 & 6.5 & 123.26 & 223 & 52\\
    \hline
    1.0 & 6.17 & {--} & 229 & {--}\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
        \end{subtable}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The table labels are messed up. I am using \item and four times and inside those each of \item I am placing this kind of table pairs, and the tables are labeled as ex: 1st \item gets 2.1 and next one 2.3 and next one 2.5.... it is not consistent. Why is that? any idea?

Comment: This was not in your post, and I'm not sure I fully understand. Could you add an example code showing what's happening?